# How to "public class FoobarID extends Long"?

Tags: java

I guess I have to accept that `Long` is `final` and cannot be extended.

In our project we use a database and pass IDs for different things around in the code as `Long`-s.

But a `UserID` is not a `LogID` and is not a `ServerID` although they're all `Long`s. It seems to me the compiler and IDE should be able to detect a whole category of bugs e.g. when trying to use a `UserID` in place of a `ServerID`. Currently the compiler doesn't detect that, because the type of both is `Long`.

If `Long` was not `final` I could say

```
public class UserID extends Long {};
```

but `Long` is `final`, so I can't. Is there something more elegant than:

```
    public class UserID {
        private Long ID;
        UserID(Long ID) {
            this.ID = ID;
        }
        UserID(UserID ID) {
            this.ID = ID.toLong();
        }
        public Long toLong() {
            return ID;
        }
        public void fromLong(Long ID) {
            this.ID = ID;
        }
    };
```

Edit: I *know* that this is inelegant - "bad"! The comments seem to assume I'm about to put something like this in my production code. I'm not.

This just seems so wasteful and inelegant. And I guess good luck getting e.g. [DbUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbutils/) to work with `UserID`s in its JavaBean handling.

Is there "a better way" (TM)? ( Other than just living with the `Long`-s ;-) )

Comment: First think about: what have `UserId`, `LogId`, `ServerId` and `WhateverId` in common and what are their differences? When you discover that, you can come up with a better design strategy.

Comment: The composition based solution is elegant enough for me if you get rid of `UserID(UserID)` and `fromLong(Long)` to make it immutable.

Comment: I can't think what Luiggi is talking about, but for me any solution here looks weird. Even your solution doesn't prevent you from making new UserId(LogId.getId()) or new UserId(100500) where 100500 is id passed by someone who has taken the id from another entity. You are just bloating your code with some overengineered solution which doesn't bring you anything.

Comment: @VadimKirilchuk that's my point, but I'm asking OP to do the mental exercise to find this rather than directly tell him about.

Comment: @MarcinKról because if you only need a `Long` there's no need to reinvent the wheel nor wrap it unless you will do something really useful with it. And this `UserId` class doesn't provide anything really useful at all. In fact, that class seems like using a flamethrower to light some candles for a birthday cake...

Comment: @MarcinKról I believe that a number must be immutable but thinking about `WhateverId` is ilogical from the beginning, making it immutable or not is not even something to think about because that solution proposal itself is useless.

Comment: @MarcinKról the question here is: why to need that? In the end, I could do something like this: `UserId userId = new UserId(someServerId.toLong());` and voila! restriction destroyed. Static type check here is useless at all, it won't protect you from anything and it will make the code messier and uglier. Again, I don't see real benefit from this approach. I find something useful for wrapping a `long` when creating something like `AtomicLong`.

Comment: @Luigi: "First think about: what have UserId, LogId, ServerId and WhateverId in common and what are their differences". I did. That is why I'd like the compiler to prevent me from doing: `Long userID = serverID`. Can we agree that if I could extend `UserID` from `Long`, that would be easy and preferable to just passing relatively typeless `Long`-s around?

Comment: I have shown you in a very small piece of code that even if you have the compiler to avoid that silly restriction, it could be bypassed by using the same constructor you left for these classes. Again, this is a bad idea at all.

Comment: Ok, @Luiggi, I'm gonna stop now. As I pointed I **NEVER EVER** intended to ship the above code! **NEVER**. I was just hoping for a way to avoid having to use the same type: `Long` for may different things, that are not the same thing. One of us is missing the other's point, and I'll stop now. Cheers.

Comment: And what I've said is: this doesn't have any sense. And I mean your purpose, because for the implementation it's the same thing.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza, I think you've misunderstood the question.  Peter is **not** asking to "avoid that silly restriction."  Quite the opposite, he is asking to add stricter typing on his IDs.  The compiler is allowing his code to easily, mistakenly mismatch one ID for another because they all are the same Long class.  He want's them to be distinct types which extend from Long, but, Java doesn't support that.  As he's explained, if Java supported MyId extends Long, and YourId extends Long, then the compiler would never let myId = yourId.

Answer (score 0):

In our project we made `Id` class that other Ids inherit, like `UserId`. Having separate Id classes helps a lot with code clarity.
Once we had an issue where function took in two Id's that where longs. And programmer put those id's in the wrong order - big problems can come from mistakes like these.
My suggestion would be to do the same, not to try extending from Long but from your own Id class. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
public abstract class Def<T extends Comparable> implements Comparable<Def<T>> {

  Comparable value = null;

  /**
   * Initializes this object. Can only be called once.
   *
   * Unfortunately, this allows us to return the wrong object type.
   *
   */
  public <C extends Def> C set(T i) {
    if (value == null) {
      value = i;
      return (C)this;
    } else {
      throw new IllegalStateException("Can only call set once!");
    }
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return value.toString();
  }

  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (o == null) {
      return false;
    }
    Class clz = this.getClass();
    Class thatclz = o.getClass();
    if (clz == thatclz) {
      return ((Def)o).value.equals(this.value);
    }
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Bad programmer! Comparing " + clz + " to " + thatclz);
  }

  @Override
  public int hashCode() {
    return value.hashCode();
  }

  public T value() {
    return (T)value;
  }

  @Override
  public int compareTo(Def<T> o) {
    return this.value.compareTo(o.value);
  }
}
```

Later:

```
static class UserID extends Def<Long> {}

UserID a = new UserID().set(81811L);
```

Comment: ID's should be immutable.  This solution would allow you to also call `a.set(200L);  a.set(300L); ... `

Answer (score -3):

Instead of using the type `Long`, use `BigInteger`. That way you can make the `UserID` extend `BigInteger`.

Comment: Are you really suggesting the man to make primary keys in his database to be BigDecimal instead of long? really? common.

Comment: No, I suggest to make the representation in Java a BigDecimal. Of course if there is a suitable abstraction that would allow a solution with inheritance, that might be a better way.

Comment: `BigDecimal` should be used to handle decimal values like 1.5. I don't see the simmilitude between this and a `Long` value who doesn't support this kind of data. Maybe you want to suggest extending from `BigInteger`, but still I don't find the benefit of doing this at all.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza yes it is a `BigInteger`of course. I adjusted it in the answer.

Comment: Assuming I did that,I'd run out of types when I need all these: NodeID, GroupID, UserID, LogID, NotificationID, SiteID, ComponentID etc.

Comment: @PeterV.Mørch: You could define you own ID type extending `BigInteger`. If not I seem to miss the point.